# sqlserver triggler instruction capture

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I would like to know it it is possible to capture the instruction that is send into a after insert trigger.

For example when I insert into table Files, I would like to capture the Instruction:
`Insert into Files (columnName01, columnName02) values ('xxxx','yyyy')`

Comment: Take a look at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/  The trigger has two tables: inserted has all the values being inserted and you can re-construct your insert statement from it.

Comment: @Pete-S- that is the way that I am currently using, are there a way to obtain the sql statement directly from sql server?

Comment: Not that I know.  Who/what is producing the SQL, can you log the SQL string manually to another table intact and retrieve it in the trigger?  Not saying that's a "great" solution; but, an option?